# How can I change opacity of an image in css without disturbing the overwritten text's opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the opacity of an image in html but don't want to change the opacity of the text that is overwritten on it.

this is my html code:-

```
<div class="image">
<img src = "C:/Users/Anmol/Desktop/NewSite/Images/background/bg_4.jpg">
<div class="text">
<h1>My Site</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is its css code:-

```
.image{
       opacity: 0.5;
       margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px
       }
 .image .text {
               position:absolute;
               text-align: center;
               top:10px;
               right:500px;
               width:300px;
               }
```

Please tell me how could I do it(if possible)?

Comment: You should never work with absolute paths to images on your disk: some manipulations wouldn't be possible due to same origin policy limitations and you'll have to change them to relative paths when deploying anyway.

Comment: Its just for testing purpose otherwise i'm going to use relative paths only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do it directly, a child element can't have an opacity greater than the one of its parent.

The easiest solution in your case is to not make the text a child of the image (have the image and the text at the same level for example):

```css
.holder {
   position: relative;
}
.image{
   opacity: 0.5;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
.text {
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:10px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class=holder>
  <div class="image">
    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/IQRCO5Lm.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>My Site</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving opacity to the parent div give opacity to the img itself. This way opacity will effect the image only leaving your text alone.

```
img{ opacity: 0.5 }
```